# SQL Server, consistency error that I can't fix

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

DBCC CHECKDB on a user database returns this error

```
Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Check Catalog Msg 3851, State 1: An invalid row (class=128,depid=65536,depsubid=0) was found in the system table sys.syssingleobjrefs (class=128).
```

This error is in a user database, not in `master`! Internet is full of articles dedicated to this error when people try to check the master database, restored on a different server. That's not the case.

I tried all usual magic without any success.

```
DBCC CHECKDB WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS
--error

ALTER DATABASE DBCopy SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

DBCC CHECKDB (DBCopy, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) 
--output reports the same error

DBCC CHECKDB WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS
--error

--no hope but just in case
ALTER DATABASE DBCopy SET EMERGENCY

DBCC CHECKDB (DBCopy, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) 
--the same error reported

DBCC CHECKDB WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS
--error

ALTER DATABASE DBCopy SET MULTI_USER
```

We don't have a backup that is free from this error.
This error appears completely harmless. The DB and apps work completely fine.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU14)

The DB is in-memory enabled.

Anything to try before I start to re-build the DB?

P.S. I rebuild the database.

Comment: The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-ver15#system-base-tables-1) says `sys.syssingleobjrefs` exists in every database, but I couldn't query it. I was trying to see the content because by the error message you got it seems some object was deleted from your database but the reference remained on that table and deleting that row would solve it. if you find how to access that table, try deleting it from a backup restored to see if it works.

Comment: @Ronaldo I can see the table when connected using DAC, but I can't DELETE this row

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have a row in `sys.syssingleobjrefs` that does not correspond to rows in other system tables.

`sys.syssingleobjrefs` is listed as a [System Base Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), and is only accessible over a DAC (administrator) connection. You can access it using `sqlcmd.exe -A`.

You also need to start SQL Server in Single User Mode. You do this by modifying the startup parameters of the service to `-m`, and restarting it.

The documentation says:

> To bind to a system base table, a user must connect to the instance of SQL Server by using the dedicated administrator connection (DAC). Trying to execute a SELECT query from a system base table without connecting by using DAC raises an error.
>
> **Important**
>
> Access to system base tables by using DAC is designed only for Microsoft personnel, and it is not a supported customer scenario.

I would only ever advise to do so when there is literally no other option. Messing with system tables can destroy your database, and apparently it sets a flag in the database header which means Microsoft may decide not to give any support on that database.

So you connect while logged in as an Administrator, or by logging in as `sa`. You probably want to just delete the invalid row, hopefully that should fix the issue.

**WARNING!:**

> Do this entirely at your own risk. I *strongly* suggest you take a backup of the database, restore it to an entirely different instance, and test this there first.

```
USE [DBCopy];
GO

ALTER DATABASE DBCopy SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

DELETE FROM sys.syssingleobjrefs
WHERE class = 128
  AND depid = 65536
  AND depsubid = 0;

GO

DBCC CHECKDB (DBCopy, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
  WITH NO_INFOMSGS, TABLOCK;

GO
```

Comment: That's a nice idea! Unfortunately, DELETE doesn't work.
Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

Comment: Hum, it seems this is not allowed anymore. What is the actual result of `SELECT * FROM sys.syssingleobjrefs WHERE class = 128   AND depid = 65536 AND depsubid = 0;` maybe there is another way to delete this row

Comment: There is only one row, the rest of columns indepid=1, indepsubid=0, status=0. I guess only Microsoft can fix issue like this, in one of CUs.

Comment: @Alsin, since the reference cannot be removed, is it possible to create the missing objects in order to match the orphaned reference?

Comment: I think the solution might be to find what object this represents and do a normal `DROP`. I just haven't had time to research that, I need to go through the hidden `resources` database to work out which object it is

Comment: Oddly enough, I can't find any system view that references `classid = 128`, so I don't know what it refers to. You could try querying every view for strange rows, perhaps you may find something which can be dropped. The only other option I can think of is to rebuild the whole database, but if it's harmless I would just leave it.

Comment: @Charlieface, that's the trick, there is no object to drop, that's why we have this issue. Yep, I'm preparing rebuild of the database.

Answer (score -3):

Repairing or deleting the corrupted lines will not work since this system table is not writable through classic T-SQL.

Depending on the size of that user database, it may be possible to dump/restore the database in order to rebuild the system catalog's and thus remove the desync between objects and catalog.

I suggest you not to backup/restore but dump/restore, because a backup/restore will keep the desync between objects and catalog.

First, make sure the application above the database is shutdown, or at least that the connection pool to database is off.

You can first set your database in single user mode (which will imply a downtime for application if it's not off).

```sql
ALTER DATABASE DBCopy SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Then through SSMS use right-click on the database concerned and select "Tasks > Generate scripts..."

Once in the following Wizard, select the objects to export (those referenced by your system table).

After the export is done, drop the objects referenced by your system table and restore them through the execution of the exported script.

Then get the database back into MULTI_USER :

```sql
ALTER DATABASE DBCopy SET MULTI_USER;
```

I suggest you, to try the procedure through a pre-production or benchmark environment first. This way, you will be able to test the solution without impacting the production at all.

PS : To find out which object is concerned by your system table, you will have to dig through the syssingleobjrefs system table (as @Charlieface said with `sqlcmd -A` which is the Administrator access through DAC).

If you don't have sqlcmd installed on the server you may have to enable "Remote DAC" to use Administrator access through network.

PS (2) : The trickiest part will probably to find out which object is related to your corrupted data since these are system and undocumented tables, it is hard to tell you what object relies behind that reference.

PS (3) : If you can't put the finger on which object is referenced by that system table. The last option would be to dump/restore all the objects of the table (which will of course involve a bigger downtime).

Comment: Yes, but this is a big job that would involve downtime...

Comment: Any of the given solutions above and even what you tried involve a downtime. And as I said, this solution is only good if the object involved in the issue is not too big.

Comment: Thank you @Hybris95, I need no help in rebuilding the database. I thought I miss something in the troubleshooting/fixing.

Comment: Sadly troubleshooting this issue is hard without Microsoft's help. You may want to open a case on their support since these system tables or undocumented. Rebuilding the database (if possible) sounds to be the only option available for now